# Adding Comments and ratings to Sharepoint document libraries or Picture libraires

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, social-networking

Is there a ready made solution to allow users to add comments to an image posted in SharePoint picture library or basically any item in a document library?

What I need is allow user who are viewing an image from a picture library for example to add comment, view comments others have left and provide some sort of voting. Similar to what you get with Facebook or Youtube.

What is the easiest way to do that? preferably something free

Comment: Am I Hot Or Not for SharePoint - I like it!

Comment: but.. what i found out.. one user can only comment once.. so it's not interactive like fb.. can it be configure to accept all comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeplex.com/sptoolbasket) you go and you can Customize as needed .